# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de encontrar el mayor elemento dentro de una lista de listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Cuál sería la manera más eficiente de determinar el máximo o mínimo dentro de una lista de listas?

Ejemplo:

matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 21, 34, 2], [4, 5, 5, 10], [10, 60, 600, 100]]

dentro de matriz, quiero encontrar el mayor elemento de la posición 2 de cada lista, sé como hacerlo con bucles, pero quisiera hacerlo de manera más eficiente y casi instantánea, pues estoy trabajando con millones de datos en tiempo real y como lo hago es poco eficiente, revise un poco acerca de `itertools` pero no encontré una manera de hacerlo, actualmente lo hago así:

```
matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 21, 34, 2], [4, 5, 5, 10], [10, 60, 600, 100]]

maximo = matriz[0][2]
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    if matriz[i][2] > maximo:
        maximo = matriz[i][2]

print(maximo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma más eficiente es usar la función preconstruida `max`. Para que compare el 2 item de cada lista se puede especificar el parámetro `key` y usar [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 21, 34, 2], [4, 5, 5, 10], [10, 60, 600, 100]]

print(max(matriz, key=itemgetter(2))[2])
```

Otra opción sin usar el módulo `operator` es usar `max` junto a un generador. Es algo más lenta pero no demasiado:

```
matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 21, 34, 2], [4, 5, 5, 10], [10, 60, 600, 100]]
print(max(item[2] for item in matriz))
```

Haciendo una pequeña comparativa de tiempos de ejecución con 400000000 listas anidadas de 4 elementos en mi caso obtengo:

> ciclo for:     70.17878007888794 segundos.
> max e itemgetter: 31.043269634246826 segundos.
> max y generador: 37.744741678237915 segundos.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, me quedo una duda en  `key=itemgetter(2))[2])` el primer 2 ¿qué significa? porque si lo cambio de 1 a 3 me sigue devolviendo el mismo valor.

Comment: @SamaelOlascoaga el primer '2' es el parámetro que se le pasa a `itemgetter()` y es el indice del elemento de cada lista que se usa para comparar. Esto retorna en realidad la lista que tiene el mayor elemento con indice 2: `[10, 60, 600, 100]`. Si lo cambias por 1 o 3 da la casualidad que es esta lista tambien la que tiene el mayor elemento con indice 1 y el mayor con indice 3 de tu ejemplo, por lo que retorna la misma lista. Si no cambias el segundo '2' retornara el 2 item de la lista que es 600 y no 60 y 100 respecivamente. No se si me he explicado bién...

Comment: Ahora si me quedo muy claro, gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Hola otra forma de hacerlo, es usando numpy

```
import numpy as np 
matriz = np.array( [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 21, 34, 2], [4, 5, 5, 10], [10, 60, 600, 100]])
print matriz[2::].max()
```